# Internet speed increases on using setInterval React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to calculate internet download speed. If I call the function only once, in useEffect(), the download speed is correctly displayed. But if I want to check it multiple times, after a specific interval, resulted speed has a strange behavior - eg increases from 43 to 200.

These are the functions from utils, used to calculate and display internet speed:

```
export function checkInternetSpeed() {
  const DOWNLOAD_SIZE = 609 * 101 * 32;
  var download = new Image();
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
      var cacheBuster = "?nnn=" + startTime;
      download.src = DOWNLOAD_IMAGE_ADDRESS + cacheBuster;
      download.id = cacheBuster;
      download.onload = () => {
      var endTime = new Date().getTime();
      showResults(endTime, startTime, DOWNLOAD_SIZE);
   };
}

export function showResults(endTime: number, startTime: number, downloadSize: number) {
  var duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000; // ms -> s
  var bitsLoaded = downloadSize * 8;
  var speedBps: number = bitsLoaded / duration;
  var speedKbps: number = speedBps / 1024;
  var speedMbps: number = speedKbps / 1024;
  console.log('youuu ' + speedMbps);
  if (speedMbps < 15) {
    message.warn('Poor network connection.');
  }
```

The corect result is shown if I call the function only once:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    checkInternetSpeed();
  }, []);
```

But if I try to calculate it on a specific interval, the speed is increasing for no reason. [image]

```
 useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    checkInternetSpeed();
  }, 60000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Maybe download image should be destroyed or onLoad execution should be stopped after every execution?
PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: *Maybe download image should be destroyed or onLoad execution should be stopped after every execution*
that sounds like a reasonable explanation, have you tried doing it?

Comment: But how? I tried to put download.src = null or download.remove()....but nothing worked

Comment: I've replicated the issue here, https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-https-jb3ly?file=/src/App.js
one of my guess is that there is some caching going on, not sure of one local level or the CDN level, can you try downloading different images with **almost** same size on each interval call?

Comment: also, these are the logs for the an random image from google: https://imgur.com/gbHm6dc (url is on the sandox)
can you please provide us the URL of the image you are downloading?

Comment: I've plugged in this url to the sandbox code, let's wait a couple of mins to see if the same thing happens

Comment: While the download speed did increase, it is not that much convincing as your results.
https://imgur.com/HcdFvhQ
Now it depends on your implementation, but it can still be the caching thing (are you on some sort of VPN?). 
the only way to check this is to try out different images/different images on different intervals.

Comment: Yes, I am using VPN

Comment: I see, that might be the case, can you try to test it on some [random image](https://www.thenerddaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Reasons-To-Watch-Anime.jpg) from google instead of the one you are using right now and see if the results are same (download speed increasing)?
My guess is that image is being served in the company's server and your are on their VPN, hence you are able to download the image so fast.
let me know the results too.

Comment: any follow up on this?

Comment: no....still no found a solution, maybe image is cached, even I am using  a cache buster "nnn="

Comment: I see, did you try downloading another image i.e. putting url of some random image from google? if so, did it gave the same results?
also, with caching I mean on your company level server, not on your local machine.